# How to pass parameters to getCurrentPosition success call back?

Tags: javascript, windows-phone-7

How can I pass in one or more parameters to a success call back when calling `navigator.geolocation.getcurrentPosition`?

How can I pass `deviceready` from `foundLoc` to `getGeoLoc` method?

```
var app = {

    onDeviceReady: function () {
        alert = window.alert || navigator.notification.alert;

        app.getGeoLoc('deviceready');
    },

    getGeoLoc: function (id) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(this.foundLoc, this.noLoc, { timeout: 3 });
    },

    foundLoc: function (position) {
        var parentElement = document.getElementById('deviceready'); 
        var lat = parentElement.querySelector('#lat');
        var long = parentElement.querySelector('#long');

        lat.innerHTML = position.coords.latitude;
        long.innerHTML = position.coords.longitude;
    },

    noLoc: function () {
        alert('device has no GPS or access is denied.');
    }
};
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Wrap the geolocation callback in **function(position) {}** as follows. Then you can add as many arguments as you want to your actual callback function.

```
var app = {

    getGeoLoc : function (id) {

        var self = this;

        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {

            var myVar1, myVar2, myVar3; // Define has many variables as you want here

            // From here you can pass the position, as well as any other arguments 
            // you might need. 
            self.foundLoc(position, self, myVar1, myVar2, myVar3)

        }, this.noloc, { timeout : 3});
    },

    foundLoc : function(position, self, myVar1, myVar2, myVar3) {},
};
```

Hope this helps anyone else who might stumble upon this.

Comment: I stumbled upon it and it certainly did help. +1 for you :)

Comment: I'm confused as to how you call this...  Can you add more to the example?

Answer (score 2):

I found this [method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22032361/how-to-pass-a-second-parameter-to-geolocation-success-function) a lot easier to understand.

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
    updatePosition(position, var1, var2);
}, errorPosition, optionsPosition);

function updatePosition(position, var1, var2) {
    var coordinates = position.coords;
}

function errorPosition(error) {
    if (err.PERMISSION_DENIED === error.code) {

    }
}

var optionsPosition = {
    enableHighAccuracy: true,
    timeout: 10000,
    maximumAge: 0
};
```