# How to pass a second parameter to geolocation success function ?

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation

This is what I'd like to do:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition( wallEventByCat( variable, position ), handle_errors );
```

in order to have this kind of callback:

```
function wallEventByCat( position, category )
{
}
```

Is this doable ? if yes, how ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use an anounymous function like:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition( function(position){
     wallEventByCat( variable, position );
}, handle_errors );
```

Comment: great thanks, bu you forgot to add position in `function( position ){ wallEventByCat( variable, position );`