# google map unable assign navigator position to class property

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Here i am using a JavaScript class to load a map with clients current location. Getting the result from the navigation geolocation but unable to assign it to class property position. Here is my class

```
var GoogleMaps = function(mapID){
    var Self = this;
    var config = {};
    this.mapID = mapID;
    this.geocoder = null;
    this.mapOptions = null;
    this.map = null;
    this.infowindow = null;
    this.marker = null;
    this.useCurrent = false;
    this.position = null;
    this.latlng = null;

    this.init = function(userCurrent){
        this.useCurrent = userCurrent;
        this.geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        this.mapOptions = {
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            mapTypeControl: false,
            navigationControlOptions: {
                style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL
            }
        };
        this.infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        this.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(this.mapID),this.mapOptions);
        this.map.setTilt(45);
        if(this.useCurrent){
            this.getPosition();
            this.setPosition();
        }
    };

    this.getPosition = function(){
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
                var currentPosition = position;
                console.log(currentPosition);//Working perfect
                this.position = position; // Not working
            });
        } else {
            error('Geo Location is not supported');
        }
    };

    this.setPosition = function(){
        //console.log('%c '+this.position,"background:orange");
        this.latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude);
    };

    this.loadMap = function(){
        this.map.setCenter(this.latlng);
        this.map.setTilt(45);
        this.map.setZoom(2);
    };
}
var Map = new GoogleMaps("map_canvas");
$(window).load(function(){
    Map.init(true);
    Map.loadMap();
});
```

checkout the getPosition function in the class.

Comment: In what way is `this.position = position;` _"Not working"_?  you get an error (if so, what?)? it remains as NULL?  it gets assigned the wrong value?

Comment: When i log the position to console getting the value perfectly,but when assigned it to position object is remains null.

Comment: So the problem is that the geolocation request in getPosition  is asynchronous.  When you then call setPosition  immediately afterwards, you're trying to refer to `this.position` before the getPosition function has had time to complete.

Comment: Here is the solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14740942/how-to-pass-parameters-to-getcurrentposition-success-call-back

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
if(this.useCurrent){
    this.getPosition();
    this.setPosition();
}
```

and

```
this.getPosition = function(){
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
            var currentPosition = position;
            console.log(currentPosition);//Working perfect
            this.position = position; // Not working
        });
    } else {
        error('Geo Location is not supported');
    }
};
```

to:

```
if(this.useCurrent){
    this.getPosition();
}
```

and

```
this.getPosition = function(){
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
            var currentPosition = position;
            console.log(currentPosition);//Working perfect
            this.position = position;
            this.setPosition();
        });
    } else {
        error('Geo Location is not supported');
    }
};
```

Comment: got the position in position property of class but map still not loading

Comment: this.setPosition(); is not a function

Comment: What's `this.setPosition = function(){`?

Comment: TypeError: this.setPosition is not a function
this.setPosition();

Comment: trying to set default latlng for google map with current position using setPosition